# Adding additional piece of logic into setters?

Tags: jsf, setter, business-logic

I have a jsf piece of view as follows:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.selectedRoleId}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.roles}" />
    <a4j:ajax event="change" listener="#{myBean.roleChanged}"
                     render="roleFeatures" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and the bean itself:

```
public class MyBean{
    private Role selectedRole;
    private Integer selectedRoleId;
    private List<SelectItem> rolesSelectItems;
    private RoleService roleService;
    //GET,SET

    public List<SelectItem> getRoles() {
        initRoles();

        return rolesSelectItems;
    }

    private void initRoles() {
        roles = new HashMap<Integer, Role>();
        rolesSelectItems = new LinkedList<SelectItem>();
        //Do some DB operations     
    }

    public void setSelectedRoleId(Integer selectedRoleId) {
        selectedRole = roleService.getBy(selectedRoleId); //Here we are getting 
                                    //actual role by its Id from database
        this.selectedRoleId = selectedRoleId;
    }

}
```

Is it considered OK to perform additional piece of logic in setters? In my particular case I got actual `Role`-entity from the DB when user selected another `Role` with `selectOneMenu`. To me, setter is a method to perform only settings a particular object and not anymore. That's why I'm asking that question.

Comment: @Tiny I heard somewhere that `@PostConstruct` is not a good annotation to use. Should we avoid using it?

Comment: @Tiny BTW, as far as I know the annotaion is only availble since JSF 2.0. But we have still some projects on JSF 1.2.

Comment: If the Role is a JPA entity object, better use @Postload

Comment: @user3694267 Yes, it is. But we're using Hibernate 3.5 and as far as I know the annotation is not available in that version....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me is ok to add additional code to a setter. For example if you know that a string can't be empty you can do something like:

```
public void setMe(String me) {
    if (me == null) {
        this.me = "";
    } else {
        this.me = me;
    }
}
```

But it is not correct adding a call to a database int the setter. This should be done in a service that calls a dao.

Comment: Well, actually `roleService.getBy` calls Dao method.

Comment: A fat -1 for not mentioning the right JSF approach for the specific problem OP is *actually* trying to solve, and hereby thus misguiding the OP and future readers looking for a solution to the same problem.